# Is really threadlocal more efficient than @RequestScope?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know that, some years ago, threadlocal was better but now I'm wondering if in the latest versions of spring boot (I'm using 2.2.6) this code here:

```
@Bean
@RequestScope
public MyPojo(){
    return new MyPojo();
}
```

Is really more efficient than:

```
public class MyControllerAspect{
    private static final ThreadLocal<MyPojo> pojo = new ThreadLocal<MyPojo>() {
          public MyPojo initialValue(){
               return new MyPojo();
          }
    }

  @Around("controllers()")
 public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse servletResponse, 
    try {
      //inject mypojo and do stuff
    }finally{
        pojo.remove(); //clean resources
     }
```

It pretty much seems the same thing Spring would already do, I feel like I'm just re-inventing the wheel could it be?
Or is this last code somewhat really more efficient?

Comment: Request scope is implemented through a `ThreadLocal`. You're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: That may be so in Spring but it should be implemented as request attributes. They should not assume a thread-based request dispatching model.

Comment: Can you be more clear about this last part?

Comment: for spring web mvc they do assume thread-based request dispatching.

Comment: ok so that should be my case: I'm using spring-boot-starter-web. Problem would come if I used starter-webflux?

Comment: Thread creation is expensive, so web servers recycle request threads in a thread pool. If you are using a `ThreadLocal` to hold stuff you don't want to share across http requests, you're going to want `finally` to invoke `dispose()` on it. But what's the worst that can happen?